# Prevent decorView background from blinking while in transition

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm creating transitions for my activities. I already set to exclude Navigation and Status Bar from transition:

```
    <targets>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
        <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
    </targets>
```

My problem is that I set the app background using:

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setBackgroundColor(COLOR);
```

And because of that, when my transition starts or finishes, this color I set before, blinks on screen between transitions. How could I prevent that? Is there any id I could put inside targets?

Answer (score 0):

From [`Transition#getTargets()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/transition/Transition.html#getTargets()):

> Returns the list of target views that this transition limits itself to tracking and animating. If the list is **null** or **empty** for `getTargetIds()`, `getTargets()`, `getTargetNames()`, and `getTargetTypes()` then this transition is not limited to specific views, and will handle changes to any views in the hierarchy of a scene change.

Transitions API will use `getTargets()` of the specified `Transition` in order to find out which `View`s need to be obtained. And as long as you have not explicitly specified a target view for the transition, then the whole view hierarchy would be obtained for changes. Hence, `decorView` will also participate in transition. Instead, you can specify as target the root of your view hierarchy, thus eliminating `decorView` from transition:

```
<fade xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <targets>
    <target android:excludeId="@android:id/statusBarBackground"/>
    <target android:excludeId="@android:id/navigationBarBackground"/>
    <target android:targetId="@id/root"/>
  </targets>

</fade>
```

> Is there any id I could put inside targets?

`decorView` has no **id** associated with it, that's why it's not possible to do via `xml`. You can inflate/acquire the `Transition` for the current window and add/exclude targets programmatically:

```
    Transition t = new Fade();

    // Inflating a transition from /transition/my_transition.xml
    // t = TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.my_transition);

    // If transition is set through theme via `android:windowExitTransition`
    // t = getWindow().getExitTransition();

    // Adding a target
    // t.addTarget(rootView);

    // Excluding decorView, which will exclude all children too
    t.excludeTarget(getWindow().getDecorView(), true);
    t.excludeTarget(android.R.id.statusBarBackground, true);
    t.excludeTarget(android.R.id.navigationBarBackground, true);

    getWindow().setExitTransition(t);
```

Comment: Hi azizbekian, I tried both here and nothing happens. I post delayed a call to supportStartPostponedEnterTransition and while the transition do not starts, the screen shows the decor view background.

Comment: I didn't say, that it won't show the background. It's just that it won't participate in transition. Your question asked how to prevent blinking. The blinking was happening, because fade transition was being applied to decorView. Do you still see it blinking?

Comment: Yes, it´s showing the background on top of everything. When I remove the post delay, it blinks this background.

Comment: You want the background not to be visible while transitioning, and get visible after transition?

Comment: I have two activities, both with same decorview background, and both have views draw above background, so the background is almost invisible. When I transition from one activity to another, this background appears above everything for an instant and then disappears and show my views. What I want is that this background do not appears above everything for an instant, I want a smootly tanstition.